# How to calculate usedGas per block?

Tags: gas, trace

I want to sum the total amount of gas used in a block.

When I checked, used gas can be retrieved from the node using 'eth_getTransactionReceipt' and 'trace_block' functions.

However, when checking the total of the used gas of the block in the two functions, it was confirmed that the sum of the used gas obtained in each function(eth_getTransactionReceipt, trace_block) was different.

Compared to etherscan, it was equal to the total sum of used gas in receipt of each transaction.

Why is the total sum of used gas in trace_block different?
In what cases is gas used other than trace in Ethereum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the total amount of used gas for each block you can use the `eth_getBlockByNumber` method. This method is returning `gasUsed` value which is the total amount of used gas by all transactions in the particular block. To use this method you have to pass the block number.

Comment: I checked `eth_getBlockByNumber` function. But, there is not has gasUsed value. so I used `eth_getTransactionReceipt` and `trace_block`...

https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API

Comment: There is ```gasUsed``` for sure, you need to test it. I'm using this method in my code and I can clearly see the ```gasUsed``` value for each block.

Comment: Oh thanks for replying! Also I made a mistake..!
However, the reason I was going to use gasUsed was to calculate the fee and burnt fee, so I needed gasUsed per tx rather than gasUsed of block..!